# What is the reason for giving "internal data flow error" message in gstreamer?

Tags: gstreamer

When i tried this command:

```
**gst-launch-0.10 -v rtspsrc location=rtsp://127.0.0.1:8554/test 
  caps="application/x-rtp,media=(string)video,clock-rate=(int)90000,
  encoding-name=(string)H264" ! rtpmp2tdepay ! mpegtsdemux ! ffdec_h264 ! autovideosink**
```

I got error as:

```
**ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:rtspsrc0/GstUDPSrc:udpsrc0: 
Internal data flow error.**
```

What is the main reason for giving error as "Internal data flow error" in gstreamer ?

Answer (score 11):

There are many potential reasons for `internal data flow` error. To encounter the problematic place, just connect a `fakesink` element step by step and try.

```
gst-launch-0.10 -v rtspsrc location=rtsp://127.0.0.1:8554/test   caps="application/x-rtp,media=(string)video,clock-rate=(int)90000,  encoding-name=(string)H264"  ! fakesink
gst-launch-0.10 -v rtspsrc location=rtsp://127.0.0.1:8554/test   caps="application/x-rtp,media=(string)video,clock-rate=(int)90000,  encoding-name=(string)H264" ! rtpmp2tdepay  ! fakesink
gst-launch-0.10 -v rtspsrc location=rtsp://127.0.0.1:8554/test   caps="application/x-rtp,media=(string)video,clock-rate=(int)90000,  encoding-name=(string)H264" ! rtpmp2tdepay  ! mpegtsdemux  ! fakesink
...
```

Answer (score 9):

It is the unfortunate case of something did not work. Rerun the command with the environment variable `GST_DEBUG="*:2"` to see all warnings.